# Как лучше/правильно реализовать структуру подсайтов

Tags: структуры, информация

Нужно реализовать сайт, подобные `пулсцен`,`tiu` и т.д
На сайте будут присутствовать `Категории` и `Товары`, для каждого поддомена свои.
На основном сайте, должен быть общий вывод информации(`Категории` и `Товары`).
Есть основной сайт, на котором регистрируешся, создается поддомен, а что дальше?

1. Создавать для каждого поддомена свою папку с cms, создавать свою БД.
2. Так же для каждого поддомена своя папка с cms и одна бд, с разделение по префиксам.
3. Иметь одну cms для всех поддоменов, при заходе на поддомен искать поддомен в бд и если находит выводить информацию из бд, у каждого поддомена своя бд.
4. Так же иметь одну cms и одну бд, и каждый поддомена выделять свой префик

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каждый поддомен должен запросы перенаправлять на основной сайт. В зависимости от того, с какого именно поддомена идёт запрос, уже на основном сайте нужны будут какие-либо отличия в отображении торговых предложений, и т.п.

То есть, для вас это 4 вариант. Лучше не плодить кучу разных CMS и баз данных, в этом нет необходимости, только загружать ресурсы сервера будете.